# How do I make a Date Time Picker only select value by datepicker not by manual

Tags: java, html, jsp, datepicker

here is my code that select from date value by user i want to select date value by datepicker only not manual entry

```
<td style="width:25%;">
<s:datetimepicker id="fromDate" key="fromDate" name='fromDate' label="Format(dd/MM/yyyy)" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" theme="simple"/>
</td>
```

Comment: 1) Don't do that to the user. 2) See 1.

Comment: 3) Make the text field for the datepicker `readonly`, but also see 1) and 2)

Answer (score 1):

Set the field to read only

```
<input type="text" name="someName" id="datePicker" readonly="readonly" />
```

Should do the trick